# Tomcat7 Manager App authentication problems

Tags: tomcat, authentication, caching, tomcat7

I'm using Tomcat7 Manager for a while without problems.
Now I need to configure in context.xml the following

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator"
       disableProxyCaching="false" />
```

I need this to allow browser caching for my application.
But with this config Tomcat Manager started to generate HTTP 403 error, the user and password aren't requested anymore. If I remove the above line the manager works again.

How can I solve this ? Use Tomcat Manager App and allow browser caching of my application ?

Comment: To anyone that has the same problem, I solved this moving the NonLoginAuthenticator configuration from the Tomcat context.xml file to the application context.xml file (META-INF/context.xml). With this, the Manager started to ask for authentication again.

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat/conf there is a tomcat-users.xml add the user

```
     <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
     <user username="tomcat" password="secret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

delete the comment blocks around user "<-->" block. ssave it.
Restart your tomcat.